# Python super() optional arguments (and mechanics of super())

Tags: python, class

I have two classes

```
class Something(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.thing = "thing"

class SomethingElse(Something):
   def __init__(self):
      self.thing = "another"
```

as you can see, one inherits from another.
When I run `super(SomethingElse)`, no error is thrown. However, when I run `super(SomethingElse).__init__()`, I was expecting an unbound function call (unbound to a hypothetical SomethingElse instance) and so was expecting that `__init__()` would complain about not receiving an object for its `self` parameter, but instead I get this error:

```
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

What is the meaning of this message?

EDIT:  I often see people hand-wave answer a `super` question, so please don't answer unless you really know how the `super` delegate is working here, and know about descriptors and how they are used with `super`.

EDIT: Alex suggested I update my post with more details. I'm getting something different now in both ways I used it for 3.6 (Anaconda). Not sure what is going on. I don't receive what Alex did, but I get:

```
class Something(object):
   def __init__(self):
   self.thing = "thing"

class SomethingElse(Something):
   def __init__(self):
      super(SomethingElse).__init__()
```

The calls (on Anaconda's 3.6):

```
SomethingElse()

<no problem>

super(SomethingElse).__init__()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: super(): no arguments 

super(SomethingElse).__init__(SomethingElse())

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not SomethingElse
```

My understanding of super was that, according to https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super, that `super()` with just the first argument would leave the `super` object unbounded to an instance, so that if you called `__init__()` on the `super` object, you'd need to pass in an instance as `__init__()` would be unbounded as well. However, 3.6 complains about how, with `super(SomethingElse).__init__(SomethingElse()`, `SomethingElse` isn't a `type`, which it should be as it inherits from a parent that inherits from `object`.

on 2.7.13 gives the original error for `super(SomethingElse).__init__()`, which was `TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)`. For `super(SomethingElse).__init__(SomethingElse())` it throws `TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not SomethingElse`

Comment: @Narendra This doesn't help. I've scoured the internet, and have seen that multiple times.

Comment: Is this python 2?

Comment: You should switch to Python version 3.6+ while you are still learning.... https://pythonclock.org/

Comment: Where are you trying to *execute* that statement?

Comment: This occurs on both 2.7.13 and 3.6.4 (3.6.4 is the Anaconda variant). Descriptors, binding, and `super` have, unfortunately, the worst documentation and outside-documentation explanations I have seen when compared to other things I have looked up for python.

There is no specific, single place in-code that I would like to run this, this is more of a Python theory/mechanics question.

Comment: For the record, this error also occurs on 2.7.13 (didn't try with 3.6.4) when that `super(SomethingElse).__init__()` is in the inheritor's `__init__()` function. The first time I ran it was outside of those two objects.

Comment: @wwii It is unproductive to assume. I have been using (Anaconda) 3.6.4 and regular 3.X before that for a while now.

Comment: Can reproduce on 2.7. Can't reproduce on 3.6.

Comment: @ben Please update your question to reflect the actual context in which you are invoking `super(SomethingElse).__init__()` - it will save some time trying to reproduce the error.  Side note: I cannot reproduce the error on Python 2.7 - I get `TypeError: unbound method __init__() must be called with SomethingElse instance as first argument (got nothing instead)` - thank you!

Comment: Thanks Alex. Updated. Did you run that `super()` call within another class's `__init__` or outside of it?

Comment: Use: `super(SomethingElse, self).__init__()`

Comment: @eyllanesc this does not answer the question. I'm looking for an understanding of the problem, and what you said does not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `super` with 1 argument produces an "unbound" super object. Those are weird and undocumented and mostly useless, and I won't go into how they were intended to be used, but for the purposes of this answer, we really only need to know one thing about them.

`super(SomethingElse).__init__` doesn't go through the usual `super` proxy logic. You're getting the `super` instance's own `__init__` method, not anything related to `SomethingElse`.

From there, the rest of the behavior follows. The `TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)` on Python 2 is because `super.__init__` takes at least 1 argument, and you're passing it 0. (You might expect it to say `TypeError: super() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)` because it's still getting `self` - the `super` object `self`, not the `SomethingElse` instance - but due to weird implementation details, methods implemented in C generally don't count `self` for this kind of error message.)

`SomethingElse()` succeeds on Python 3 because the `super` constructor pulls `__class__` and `self` from the usual stack inspection magic.

Calling `super(SomethingElse).__init__()` manually from outside the class produces `RuntimeError: super(): no arguments` because `super.__init__` tries to do its stack inspection magic and doesn't find `__class__` or `self`.

`super(SomethingElse).__init__(SomethingElse())` fails because the first argument to the `super` constructor is supposed to be a type, not an instance.

Comment: Why does `super` expect a type during `__init__` when I've already given it one in the call `super(SomethingElse)`? The Python documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super)  doesn't suggest that it would lose track of its type.

Comment: @ben: Because `__init__` expects a type. It doesn't matter whether you already provided one. You're calling the constructor again, and you need to provide all constructor parameters.

Comment: If you think that's weird, well, calling the constructor of a constructed object is weird.

Comment: Right, but when you call `super(SomethingElse, SomethingElse()).__init__()`, it doesn't use `super`'s constructor, which is why this is getting confusing.